# Can someone help me solve this misunderstanding please.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-isomorphism

Is it a good way to determine isomorphic of two graphs by comparing their adjacent vertices? If their is a different then they are not isomorphic? If they have the same then they are isomorphic? Since they have same number of vertices and each vertex have the same degree. If not, then give an appropriate way of finding their isomorphic please.

Comment: I think you've got it right. If you have two graphs and you can draw them to look exactly the same then they are isomorphic.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - are you asking whether listing the orders of the vertices of two graphs (eg in descending order, with repetitions) is sufficient to prove they are isomorphic?

Comment: They are look exactly the same except one thing. Some of the order of their adjacent vertices are different when I compared them.

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough that the graphs have the same number of vertices of the same degree.  For example, two disjoint triangles and the hexagon, each have six vertices of degree 2.  You are describing the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), which is known to be quite hard in general.

To elaborate a little, two graphs are isomorphic if you can pair off the vertices of one with the vertices of the other, and the resulting adjacency matrices are identical.  In the example above, $$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$$
and 
 $$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$$
there is no way to rearrange the vertices of either graph (which will rearrange rows/columns of the matrix), to make the matrices agree.

Comment: I don't know what else can I do if it is known to be quite hard in general, but there is no disjoint in each graph here not as you gave in your example.

Comment: @siamoka, it's just an example.

Comment: OK, let use your example above but their is no disjoint. Two graph are hexagon, all vertices of degree 3. Are they isomorphic?

Comment: @Siamoka Not necessarily. There are at least two connected graphs with six vertices all of degree three: In a hexagon $ABCDEF$ add diagonals $AD, BE, CF$ or add diagonals $AE, BD, CF$. Only one of them has 3-cycles, so they are not isomorphic.

Comment: From your work above, if the graph wasn't isomorphic. What will be your work look like. For that kind of problem similar to above graph such as heptagon, octagon etc. What will be the simple way to find out their isomorphic?